# How to modify dates with NSDateComponents

Tags: ios, nsdatecomponents

I have this string which is passed to this method to produce 2 times:

> Mon thru Friday 7:00 AM - 10:00 PM

And I use this code to split up the string into two times; opening and closing times:

```
-(void)dealWithTimeStrings2:(NSString*)timeString{
    <...IRRELEVANT CODE PARSING STRING INTO DATES...>

    NSLog(@"openDate hours %@, openDate minutes %@", openHours, openMinutes);
    NSLog(@"closeDate hours %@, closeDate minutes %@", closeHours, closeMinutes);
    NSLog(@"nowDate hours %@, nowDate minutes %@", nowHours, nowMinutes);

    //COMPARE HOURS
    if ([openHours intValue] < [nowHours intValue] < [closeHours intValue]) {
        NSLog(@"ABIERTO-dateComponents");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"CERRADO-dateComponents");
    }

    NSLog(@"open, now, close %@,%@,%@", openDate,[NSDate date], closeDate);


    if ([self timeCompare:openDate until:closeDate]) {
        NSLog(@"OPEN-timeCompare");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"CLOSED-timeCompare");
    }
}
```

This produces these logs in the console:

```
someDateString 7:00 AM,10:00 PM  
openDate hours 13, openDate minutes 00 
closeDate hours 04, closeDate minutes 00  
nowDate hours 14, nowDate minutes 51  
OPEN-dateComponents  
open, now, close 2000-01-01 13:00:00 +0000,2013-07-25 14:51:16 +0000,2000-01-02 04:00:00 +0000 2013-07-25 08:51:16:486  
CLOSED-timeCompare
```

I now wish to test if now time falls between the opening and closing times. But if you notice, open and close times are in the year 2000-01-01 & 2000-01-02 whereas now is in 2013-07-24. Here is the test code:

```
-(BOOL)timeCompare:(NSDate*)date1 until:(NSDate*)date2{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                            initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components =
    [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    return ([date compare:date1] == NSOrderedDescending && [date compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending);
}
```

Is it failing because of the date part?  The fact that its a different year for the opening and closing dates vs the now date?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)timeCompare:(NSDate*)date1 until:(NSDate*)date2 {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components =
    [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    return ([date compare:date1] == NSOrderedDescending && [date compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending);
}
```

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the code you wrote.  You were missing a fromDate: but Im also not sure what you are using NSDate *date for and you didnt define now.  Thx

Comment: I updated the answer to fix the method calling and declare. The idea was to create a "normalized" date, so you can compare with the other ones.

Comment: Ok I did, but the test fails.  I just ran the code above as mentioned, but replaced timeCompare method with the one you gave.  I just updated the results above.